# Meteor helper not running reactively

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, meteor-blaze

I am using the `mizzao:user-status` package to make a list of online users.

Note that the following code is coffeescript, which has been working fine especially since I'm sticking with Blaze instead of React (I haven't found a way to use JSX in coffeescript).

Tangent aside, I'm specifically having an issue with the `users.helpers` in `client.coffee`. The `debugger` is only called once, and when I inspect the `users_data` variable in there it shows an empty array. It's clear that at least some part of this is working reactively, since when I continue past the breakpoint and check the value of `users_data` again, it is nonempty. But the return value of the `users` helper does not seem to change. The function doesn't re-run.

tl;dr

**how to make the `users` helper method rerun when `users_data` changes**

```
# ------------------
# server.coffee
# ------------------

Meteor.publish 'user_status', ->
  Meteor.users.find(
    { "status.online": true },
    fields: {}
  )

# ------------------
# client.coffee
# ------------------

Meteor.subscribe 'online_users'
users = Template.users
users.helpers
  users: ->
    window.users_cursor = Meteor.users.find
      "status.online": true
    window.users_data = users_cursor.collection._docs._map
    debugger
    window.final = Object.keys(users_data).map (_id) =>
      user = users_data[_id]
      {
        _id,
        name: user.profile.name
      }
    final
```

and the relevant part of the Blaze template:

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> loginButtons }}
  {{> users}}
</body>

<template name="users">
  {{#each users}}
    <li>{{_id}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, it's not a bug in Meteor itself and wasn't too difficult to correct.

This whole thing was unnecessary:

```
  users: ->
    window.users_cursor = Meteor.users.find
      "status.online": true
    window.users_data = users_cursor.collection._docs._map
    debugger
    window.final = Object.keys(users_data).map (_id) =>
      user = users_data[_id]
      {
        _id,
        name: user.profile.name
      }
    final
```

Instead this suffices:

```
users: ->
  Meteor.users.find({})
```

The `Meteor.users.find` result is not an array and doesn't respond to `[0]` style indexing, which is why I didn't think that it would be suitable as a return value for the helper. However it does respond to `forEach`. That's why it works with the following refactor of the template:

```
<template name="users">
  {{#each user in users}}
    <li>{{user._id}</li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The one problem remaining is that `Meteor.users.find("status.online": true)` doesn't work still, it must be `find({})` instead. I'll work on that and possibly post a question about it.

Comment: To be more precise, it is the other way around: the [`each`](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each) Blaze template tag expects a Meteor collection cursor, but it can also be a plain array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to maxple's answer, you can also do this in your HTML code:

```
<template name="users">
  {{#each users}}
    {{this._id}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```